# Shortcut to calling part of the Python code on CMD

Tags: function, argparse

I have a code that updates information from 3 accounts, I want to be able to use a shortcut on the command line to update based off the account that I want. Currently the fix is having 3 different python codes. I want just one code that will have a shortcut to execute 1st function, 2nd function, 3rd function, and all. I think I need to use argparse but where I'm stuck is trying to run the code based off 1 of the accounts. Part of code below.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    def _msg(updated):
        return "was updated" if updated else "already up-to-date"
    
   
    
    Cloud_Updater = Cloud()
    updated = Cloud_Updater.update()
    print("Cloud {}.\n".format(_msg(updated)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` can handle this via default values for an otherwise "hidden" option. This is adapted from the example in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

# Assumed definitions of HCM, SHC, cloud, and _msg

parser = ArgumentParser()
subparser = p.add_subparsers(dest='name')
subparser.add_parser("hcm").set_defaults(updater=HCM().update)
subparser.add_parser("shc").set_defaults(updater=SHC().update)
subparser.add_parser("cloud").set_defaults(updater=Cloud().update)

args = parser.parse_args()
updated = args.updater()
print("{} {}.".format(args.name, _msg(updated)))
```

Then a command like

```
myscript hcm
```

will produce either

```
hcm was updated
```

or

```
hcm was already up-to-date
```

as output.

---

To be able to run any subset of the three, I would get rid of the subparsers and use ordinary options. Something like

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--hcm", action='append_const', const=('hcm', HCM().update), dest='updaters')
parser.add_argument("--shc", action='append_const', const=('shc', SHC().update), dest='updaters')
parser.add_argument("--cloud", action='append_const', const=('cloud', Cloud().update), dest='updaters')
parser.set_defaults(updaters=[])

args = parser.parse_args()
for name, updater in args.updaters:
    updated = updater()
    print("{} {}.".format(name, _msg(updated)))
```

Comment: This worked, except it only outputs the HCM even when I use the command "shc" and "cloud". Is this because it's the default method? I also kindly ask how I would be able to call all 3? would it be something like this: subparser.add_parser("all").set_defaults(updater=Cloud(),updater=SHC(),updater=HCM().update)

Comment: Hm; after fixing this, I do get `hcm`, `shc`, or `cloud` as appropriate.

Comment: Hi, this works now thank you. How can I add an argument that calls all 3?